# Why return const Rational rather than Rational

Tags: c++

I saw the following implementation of the operator* as follows:

```
class Rational {
public: 
       Rational(int numerator=0, int denominator=1);
       ...
private:
       int n, d; // numerator and denominator
       friend const Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs)
      { 
          return Rational(lhs.n * rhs.n, lhs.d * rhs.d); 
      }    
};
```

I have two questions here:

- Q1> why the operator* has to return
  const Rational rather than simply
  Rational
- Q2> when we define a friend function, should we care about the access modifier?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. So that you can't do something like `Rational a, b, c; (a * b) = c;`.
2. No.

Answer (score 10):

Note that returning `const Rational` instead of `Rational` not only prevents nonsensical assignments but also move semantics (because `Rational&&` does not bind to `const Rational`) and is thus not recommended practice anymore in C++0x.

Scott Meyers wrote a [note](http://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/mec++-errata.html) on this matter:

> Declaring by-value function return values const will
>   prevent their being bound to rvalue references in C++0x.
>   Because rvalue references are designed to help improve
>   the efficiency of C++ code, it's important to take
>   into account the interaction of const return values
>   and the initialization of rvalue references when
>   specifying function signatures.

Comment: For an example of move semantics, think `a*b*c;` by overloading `operator*` with `&&` arguments, we can get destructible temporaries to steal resources from, and thus remove unnecessary allocations from chains of operators.

Comment: @Mat: Although it's rather unlikely that `Rational` has any external resources, but think `string` or similar types and my argument is valid :)

Comment: I agree, actually I was trying to extend your answer with an example of when move semantics would apply :)